# How to specify a type for the response body in a Nextjs route handler

Tags: typescript, next.js

```
interface DefaultResponse<T> {
  success: boolean;
  message?: string;
  user?: T;
}

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const body: Pick<User, 'email' | 'password'> = await req.json();

  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email: body.email } });

  if (!user) {
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: 'email is invalid', success: false }),
    );
  }

  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({ message: '', sueecss: true, user }),
  ) as DefaultResponse<User>; // This method will not work.
}
```

The code above checks to see if the email is valid and responds with the member information if it matches.

By specifying a type for the body
Like the code above, I want to specify a type to warn an error if success is misspelled. How can I specify a type in the response body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast the value of `JSON.stringify(...)`, which is a string to `DefaultResponse`. This will error, but not for the reason you would like.

I'd recommend typing the return value of the handler function instead, and using `Response.json()` or (`NextResponse.json()`, like so:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

interface DefaultResponse<T> {
  success: boolean;
  message?: string;
  user?: T;
}

export async function POST(req: Request): Promise<NextResponse<DefaultResponse<User>>> {
  const body: Pick<User, 'email' | 'password'> = await req.json();

  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email: body.email } });

  if (!user) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'email is invalid', success: false });
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ message: '', sueecss: true, user })
}
```

Also you might want to remove the password field from the user object retrieved from Prisma, before sending it back in the response. See: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/excluding-fields

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this has helped me tremendously!

Comment: I'm also developing web using Next.js api route without a server, is there any difference between doing this without a server and having a server?